# Environment variables in an Android project

Tags: android

Is there a way to set environment variables in an Android project? For example, in a situation where you want to use your app with different webservers in development and production, where could you place the different URLs for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> For example, in a situation where you want to use your app with different webservers in development and production, where could you place the different URLs for this?

If you are using Android Studio, this is handled by configuring your build types.

In your `android` closure, you can have a `buildTypes` closure where you define constants to be added to the `BuildConfig` class:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
          buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://test.this-is-so-fake.com"'
        }

        release {
          buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://prod.this-is-so-fake.com"'
        }
    }
```

Now, in my Java code, I can refer to `BuildConfig.SERVER_URL`. A `debug` build will give me the debug URL; a `release` build will give me the release URL. You can create your own custom build types for more complex scenarios as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I realized after reading your answer I was just Googling the wrong thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499455/promotion-of-app-from-beta-to-production-on-google-play-working-with-build-varia

@CommonnsWare can you please tell us how can i achieve this.

1 apk move from beta to prod but pointing to diff URL.

Comment: @Mahesh: I personally do not use Play Store's beta system, and so I do not have any direct experience with it.