# Promotion of app from beta to production on Google Play working with Build Variants

Tags: android, url, gradle, google-play-console, build-variant

I have the follow situation

## Scenario

**Part 1.** An app working with `Build Variants`: `debug`, `beta` and `release` as follow

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"url local test"'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    beta {
        versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"url homologation"'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"url production"'
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

And a call to use `String SERVER_URL` pointing to current url by `buildType selected`. Look this

```
String URL = BuildConfig.SERVER_URL
```

**Part 2.** The switch between `Build Variants` by Android Studio, as follow image

[image]

It's working absolutelly fine for me

## Issue

**Part 1.** I have the app on Google Play production **generated as signed apk from release variant**

**Part 2.** I need put the app on Google Play beta test **generating as signed apk from BETA variant**, e.g, pointing to `url homologation`

**Part 3.** When the product owner finish the tests from beta test, I go need promote the same app to production by Google Play Console

## Question

**The core question:** When I go promote the app from beta to production, it one will point automatically to `url production` by `release variant` or I will need generate another apk as `signed apk from release variant`?

**Why?** The main motivation is beacause I can't test this promotion without safe assurance that it will work fine, and no less important, this would save my time and my own chef would can do it

**Alert!** If it is wrong job, what the best pratice to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question it is this:

- with your current setup, you have some configuration compiled into the APK, including a server URL
- you want to test with one server in beta, and a different one in release
- but this means you can't promote your beta APK to release, because the URL would be different. But if you re-compile, you can't be sure the APK remains unchanged from the one you tested.

You are right, this is a real problem. There are two common solutions:

- Option 1: don't compile your server strings into your APK. Instead, use a service like [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to dynamically change the server and other settings for your beta. That way the APK doesn't need to change
- Option 2: When you build your beta build, tag your branch in your version control system. Then when you want to promote to prod, build a new APK, but make sure you are using the tagged branch from the version control system.

Personally I think I would recommend option 1, but I know different large professional android developers use both options.

Comment: Your answer are satisfactory. Means then that I need review my skills on Android Development. Thank you very much. Have you any link point me to Gradle patterns?